# Controller (MVC) gives back JSON with "$ref": "15" as reference to other objects

Tags: json, model-view-controller

At the moment we get JSON back with references to objects that were rendered previous. We expect that JSON objects are full rendered.

When we get the result of a function in a controller we get a $ref id in stead of the full JSON object. For example:

This is what we expect:

```
     "TaxCode": {
      "Name": "Hoog (21%)",
      "Rate": 21,
      "CreatedOn": "2020-01-06T14:45:28",
      "ModifiedOn": "2020-01-23T09:11:27.653",
      "DeletedOn": null,
      "Id": 1,
      "SqlLabelTemplate": null,
      "Label": "Hoog (21%)"
    },
```

This is what we get:

```
    "TaxCode": {
      "$ref": "15"
    },
```

This is the config setting we currently have:

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

We tried different values in the config with no result.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow there was a config added to the WebApiConfig.cs. So the config in the global.asax was overwritten.

After removing this line from the webapiconfig.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

And adding the following config to the Global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

solved all issues.